# How do I get Mathematica to invert a matrix with subscripts involved? (Subscript usage)

Tags: summation, subscript, indexed-variable

I want *Mathematica* to invert a matrix in which all variables are symbolic including [`Subscript`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Subscript.html). Now I am guessing this has something to do with the method I'm defining the variables in the summation, especially the use of `Subscript`.

But I am worried that since `Subscript` are for presentation purposes, I don't want to use them and I looking for an alternate way to do this.

As an example, consider the matrix below

```
A = { {F11 * Sum[Subscript[towpx^2, i], {i, 1, n}] + 
 F22 * Sum[Subscript[fpx^2, i], {i, 1, n}], 
Sum[F11 * Subscript[towpx, i], {i, 1, n}]*
  Sum[Subscript[towpy, i], {i, 1, n}] + 
 F22 * Sum[Subscript[fpx, i], {i, 1, n}]*
  Sum[Subscript[fpy, i], {i, 1, n}] } , { 
F11* Sum[Subscript[towpx, i], {i, 1, n}]*
  Sum[Subscript[towpy, i], {i, 1, n}] + 
 F22 * Sum[Subscript[fpx, i], {i, 1, n}]*
  Sum[Subscript[fpy, i], {i, 1, n}]  , 
F11 * Sum[Subscript[towpy^2, i], {i, 1, n}] + 
 F22 * Sum[Subscript[fpy^2, i], {i, 1, n}]} };
```

**How can I Invert a matrix that needs to have variables with `Subscript` for display?**

I am very new to *Mathematica*and don't understand any of the stuff in general posts regarding correct syntax usages (Apologies if the post isn't appropriate)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: "simplest possible way on how to deal with this issue" - avoid subscripts for computational work, and reserve them for formatting; they're more trouble than they're worth.

Comment: `Inverse[A]` works for me.

Comment: @J.M. okay, thank you. but what alternative would you suggest?

Comment: @MichaelE2 , yes it does. But I am worried that since subscripts are for presentation purposes, I don't want to use them and I looking for an alternate way to do this.

Comment: (1) You might want to edit the question to clarify what you want, since I read the main issue as "I want Mathematica to invert a matrix." (2) The same problem exists for mathematical papers in general. One idea is to represent each type of sum by its own short symbol/variable/string. Or just $A^{-1}$, since formulas for inverses are often unreadably complicated.

Comment: From what you've said so far, it seems you may just want `Indexed` instead of `Subscript`.  (Unfortunately, it does not display quite as nicely when combined with `Power`.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rewrite your matrix (notice I'm fixing a the erroneous `Subscript[towpx^2, i]` that should be `Subscript[towpx, i]^2`.

```
b = A /. {Subscript[Power[var_, exp_], index_] -> 
    Power[var[index], exp], Subscript[var_, index_] -> var[index]}
```

Define an UpValue rule for displaying `var[index]` as `Subscript[var,index]` for the vars of interest.

```
(# /: Format[#[i_]] := Subscript[#, i]) & /@ {fpx, fpy, towpy, towpx}
```

now

[image: Mathematica graphics]

but the [`FullForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FullForm.html), i.e the form *Mathematica* uses for internal calculations, is still free of `Subscript`

[image: Mathematica graphics]

and the inverse is just

```
Inverse[b]
```