# Why can't Mathematica simplify this? (FullSimplify usage)

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, simplifying-expressions, summation

I have an expression like this (the one shown below is a generic form)

$$ (F22)^3\left(\sum_{k=1}^n a_k\right)^2 \left(\sum_{k=1}^n d_k\right)^2 \left[\left(\sum_{k=1}^n b_k^2\right)  - \left(\sum_{k=1}^n b_k\right)^2 \right] + (F22)^3\left(\sum_{k=1}^n c_k^2\right) \left(\sum_{k=1}^n b_k\right) \left(\sum_{k=1}^n d_k\right) \left[\left(\sum_{k=1}^n a_k^2\right)  - \left(\sum_{k=1}^n a_k\right)^2 \right] + (F11)(F22)^2\left(\sum_{k=1}^n e_k^2\right) \left(\sum_{k=1}^n c_k^2 \right) \left(\sum_{k=1}^n b_k\right) \left(\sum_{k=1}^n d_k\right) - (F11)(F22)^2\left(\sum_{k=1}^n e_k\right) \left(\sum_{k=1}^n f_k \right) \left(\sum_{k=1}^n a_k\right) \left(\sum_{k=1}^n b_k\right) \left(\sum_{k=1}^n d_k\right)^2 $$

F11 and F22 are constants. The $a_k$ and other such things being summed are actual values that we get from calculations/simulations but right now I am deriving closed form expressions. I encountered this while working on passive radars for my Masters thesis.

I used symbolic indexed variables and then applied FullSimplify, yet the expression remains the same. I tried to do this by hand for a while, but I could not find a way so I thought Mathematica should be able to handle it.

Please guide me on how to properly simplify such expressions.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: 1) please post code, not latex; in order to try to help you, we need access to your expression. 2) what kind of simplification are you looking for? If you couldn't find one by hand, then perhaps there is no simpler form.

Comment: I think that's it. `FullSimplify[(F22)^3*a^2*d^2*(b2 - b^2) + (F22)^3*c2*b*
   d*(a2 - a^2) + (F11)*(F22)^2*e2*c2*b*d - F11*(F22)^2*e*f*a*b*d^2, 
 TimeConstraint -> Infinity]`

Comment: @MarcoB , I already posted the code in one of the questions because I needed some help and someone helped me and therefore I know that is correct. And all I want to know is that if FullSimplify can't do it, then does it mean it can't be done?

Comment: @S.Khan where did you post the code? Add a link to this question referring to where the code can be found. Also, `FullSimplify` simply tries its best. There I see no guarantee that it will always return the simplest form, also because the definition of "simpler" changes with context.

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk , tried that code already, but I used indexed variables with summation (as pointed out by many that those should be used in place of subscript). but still I end up getting the same mess that I get on paper i.e. by hand.

Comment: @MarcoB , the full code is too lengthy to post but I posted one of the matrices that ultimately led to the situation that I am describing.

https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/156602/how-do-i-get-mathematica-to-invert-a-matrix-with-subscripts-involved-subscript

And my current code involves the corrections in the answer.

Comment: You should mention that you also simultaneously posted this same question at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2450205/how-does-one-simplify-expressions-in-which-the-terms-are-products-of-multiple-su.  And @MariuszIwaniuk already gave you the answer.

Comment: @JimB , what MariuszIwaniuk wrote I knew that already and that did not solve my problem. My question was that WHY is mathematica not simplifying it or reducing it into smaller form? That is still unanswered.

Comment: You are missing the point.  Simultaneous posting is not the problem. 
 But what you've done is set two different groups of experts working on your problem in complete isolation of each other.  One group won't know if the other group has either solved the problem or made progress.  That wastes those folks' time.  So if you do post simultaneously in the future, please inform all of the other postings.

Answer (score 1):

This is an extended comment.  I think you need to give an example of what you believe to be a simplification given the kind of summations you have.  Consider the following bare bones code:

```
x = Sum[a[i], {i, 1, n}] (Sum[b[j], {j, 1, n}] + Sum[c[k], {k, 1, n}])
```

or equivalently

$$\left(\sum _{i=1}^n a(i)\right) \left(\sum _{j=1}^n b(j)+\sum _{k=1}^n c(k)\right)$$

In my mind there is no simplification (unless $a$, $b$, and $c$ are explicitly related which you haven't mentioned).  Might you consider the following a simplification?

```
Distribute[x]
```

with the result being

$$\left(\sum _{i=1}^n a(i)\right) \sum _{j=1}^n b(j)+\left(\sum _{i=1}^n a(i)\right) \sum _{k=1}^n c(k)$$

Comment: What I believe is that there is no simplification for the kind of expression that I posted, meaning that I can't just reduce it to a one liner e.g. think of a^2 + b^c + c^2 + 2ab + 2bc + 2ca = (a+b+c)^2.

I just wanted to confirm my belief. I agree with what you posted in this answer. All I can do in my case is just group things on the basis of the common factors (e.g. writing your answer's second eq. in the form of the first one). But thank you for your answer.